# MSIX: Icon in Windows' "Apps & Features" panel grayed out

Tags: image, icons, assets, msix

I have a simple image (white text in front of a green background) that is used to generate all the different assets in my MSIX project:

[image]

All good and well. However, for some reason, that image appears as greyed out in the Windows 10 "Apps & Features" panel:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. Anybody else having experienced this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to registry and find your application in the following key.

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\StateChange\PackageList`

Remove your application from the list. This will ungray application icon. For some reason the OS will mark this application with a status that tells it that there is an issue with an application when there clearly isn't.

Although this answers the part why the icon is gray it doesn't address the core issue which is - why does the OS mark the application with this status?

You can check that the PackageStatus subkey has a value of `20000`. If you change the status to `0` this will also ungray the icon.

**EDIT**

I have also found out that if I publish this package without the ability to update from an URL the application will not be grayed out. I guess in cases where you need the application to auto update this will happen for some reason.